# Display overlapping subtitles

Tags: davinci-resolve, subtitles

I used YouTube to autogenerate subtitles for a video. The srt file looks something like this:

```
0:00:00.060,0:00:07.080
first caption

0:00:03.240,0:00:09.599
second caption

0:00:07.080,0:00:13.019
third caption
```

---

As you can see, the captions overlap in time. The `first caption` is present for seconds 0-7, while the `second caption` is present for seconds 3-9. The result in YouTube is that:

- The `first caption` appears first and is the first line on the screen.
- Then on second 3 the `second caption` appears as the second line.
- On second 7 the `first caption` disappears and the `second caption` becomes the first line. At the same time, `third caption` appears as the second line.

---

However, when I use the srt in DaVinci Resolve, only a single line appears at a time. So:

- The `first caption` stays there until second 7.
- The `second caption` appears only between seconds 7 and 9.
- The `third caption` appears after second 9.

---

Is there a way to display such multiline subtitles with DaVinci Resolve?

If not, how do I fix it so it displays properly with one caption at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that I couldn't find a satisfying solution, I wrote [a Ruby script](https://gist.github.com/ndnenkov/c9e1d74fce110da4a21fbb7979895024) for merging such overlapping captions.

Usage:

```
ruby ./merge_overlapping_srt_captions.rb _input_file_ _output_file_
```